# Function returns only letters of string

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I wrote a program that should take a string and then return a string with only letters from the original one, but it's not working and can't figure out why. Can someone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *only_letters(char *s1ptr, char *s2ptr)
{
    while(*s1ptr)
    {
        if((*s1ptr >= 'a' && *s1ptr <= 'z') || (*s1ptr >= 'A' && *s1ptr <= 'Z'))
        {
            *s2ptr = *s1ptr;
            s2ptr++;
        }
        s1ptr++;
    }
    *s2ptr = '\0';
    return s2ptr;
}

int main()
{
    char *s1ptr, *s2ptr;
    printf("\n Write a string:\n");
    scanf("%s", s1ptr);
    printf("\n%s\n", *only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to remove non-alphabetical characters from the string?

Comment: yes, it says in the beginning

Comment: As was said before, "This is C code, not C++...." Nothing in the question or sample points to C++. Do you require a C++ solution? Then remove the [C] tag.

Comment: `char *only_letters(); printf("\n%s\n", *only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr))`  implies not all compiler warnings are enabled as `"%s"` does not belong with a `char`.  Turn on all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 problems.

1. `s1ptr` and `s2ptr` are two unallocated arrays which will be caused to undefined behavior.
2. You're incrementing `s2ptr` to the point which has value `\0`. After returning it you will have a string that just has `\0`.
3. To show a string, you must pass it without `*` (don't dereference it).

Try this

```
char *only_letters(char *s1ptr, char *s2ptr_)
{
    char *s2ptr = s2ptr_;
    while(*s1ptr)
    {
        if((*s1ptr >= 'a' && *s1ptr <= 'z') || (*s1ptr >= 'A' && *s1ptr <= 'Z'))
        {
            *s2ptr = *s1ptr;
            s2ptr++;
        }
        s1ptr++;
    }
    *s2ptr = '\0';

    return s2ptr_;
}

int main()
{
    char s1ptr[256]; // Long enough
    char s2ptr[256]; // Long enough
    printf("\n Write a string:\n");
    scanf("%s", s1ptr);
    printf("\n%s\n", only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You run into undefined behavior because `s1ptr` doesn't point to a valid location, and so the `scanf` fails.

Try declaring your variables as

```
char s1ptr[64], s2ptr[64]; //or whatever length suits you
```

Also, note that

```
printf("\n%s\n", *only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr));
```

will attempt to dereference what `only_letters` returns (which is a `char*`, dereferenced is a `char`), but you're attempting to read it as a string (via the `%s`). Remove the dereference operator.

Comment: I changed it but know it always prints `(null)`

Comment: What did you expect?  You're returning a pointer that points to ASCII 0: `*s2ptr = '\0';    return s2ptr;`

Comment: @User231454 also, why are you dereferencing the function return? that just prints a single char.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely ugly C-style code, easy to get wrong. While the bugs in your code have been fixed by earlier birds, here is the C++ way to do this:

```
std::string only_letters (std::string input) {
    auto it = std::remove_if(input.begin(),input.end(),
        [](const char x) {return !std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(x));});
    input.erase(it,input.end());
    return input;
}

int main () {
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Write a string:\n";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << only_letters(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that you're using invalid pointers, you're also using the wrong format specifier:

```
printf("\n%s\n", *only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr));
```

Since `only_letter` returns a `char*`, dereferencing its result produces a `char`.
Your format says to expect a pointer to a zero-terminated character sequence ("%s") so `printf` will interpret the `char` you passed to it as a pointer. 
In your case, you're returning a pointer to the final `'\0'` character, and the zero happens to be interpreted as a null pointer, printed as "(null)".
You'll need to save the initial value of the result pointer before you start.

A possibly complete, untested fix:

```
char *only_letters(char *s1ptr, char *s2ptr)
{
    char* result = s2ptr;
    while(*s1ptr)
    {
        if((*s1ptr >= 'a' && *s1ptr <= 'z') || (*s1ptr >= 'A' && *s1ptr <= 'Z'))
        {
            *s2ptr = *s1ptr;
            s2ptr++;
        }
        s1ptr++;
    }
    *s2ptr = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char s1ptr[1024], s2ptr[1024];
    printf("\n Write a string:\n");
    scanf("%s", s1ptr);
    printf("\n%s\n", only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has at least three defects. The first one is in the function definition

```
char *only_letters(char *s1ptr, char *s2ptr)
{
    while(*s1ptr)
    {
        if((*s1ptr >= 'a' && *s1ptr <= 'z') || (*s1ptr >= 'A' && *s1ptr <= 'Z'))
        {
            *s2ptr = *s1ptr;
            s2ptr++;
        }
        s1ptr++;
    }
    *s2ptr = '\0';
    return s2ptr;
}
```

The function returns pointer to the terminating zero

```
*s2ptr = '\0';
return s2ptr;
```

The valid code could look the following way

```
char * only_letters( const char *s1ptr, char *s2ptr )
{
    char *p = s2ptr;

    while ( *s1ptr )
    {
        if ( ( *s1ptr >= 'a' && *s1ptr <= 'z' ) || ( *s1ptr >= 'A' && *s1ptr <= 'Z' ) )
        {
            *p++ = *s1ptr;
        }
        s1ptr++;
    }

    *p = '\0';

    return s2ptr;
}
```

As for me then I would write the function as

```
char * only_letters( const char *s1ptr, char *s2ptr )
{
    char *p = s2ptr;

    while ( *s1ptr )
    {
        if ( isalpha( *s1ptr ) )
        {
            *p++ = *s1ptr;
        }
        s1ptr++;
    }

    *p = '\0';

    return s2ptr;
}
```

The second defect is that you did not allocate memory where you are going to write data.

```
int main()
{
    char *s1ptr, *s2ptr;
    //...
```

Thr valid code could look as for example

```
int main()
{
    const size_t N = 20;
    char s1ptr[N], s2ptr[N];
```

Take into account that instead of

```
printf("\n%s\n", *only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr));
```

there has to be

```
printf("\n%s\n", only_letters(s1ptr, s2ptr));
```

And the third defect is the using of function `scanf` to read a string. This function can override memory that is not belong to the array.

```
scanf("%s", s1ptr);
```

It is better to use function `fgets`

For example

```
fgets( s1ptr, N, stdin );
```

And at last if the program is written in C then main shall be defined as

```
int main( void )
```

If by accident:) it is a C++ program then you should use standard C++ streams instead of C streams and corresponding C++ functions instead of C functions.

Also you could use standard algorithm `std::copy_if` that to copy in the destination string only alpha characters.